# event streaming via mongodb. Get last inserted events

Tags: mongodb

I consuming data from existing database. this database store system events. My service should check this database by timer, check if some new events created, then upload it and handle. Something like simple queue implementation.

The question is - how can I get **new** docs each time, when I check database. I can't use timestamps, because events goes to database from different sources and there are no any order for events. So I just need to use inserting order only.

Comment: What does your MongoDB setup look like?  Simple server, Replica-set, or Sharded?

Comment: For now it's simple server, but I think in future it will goes to shrded state.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of options.

The first, and easiest if it matches your use case, is to use a capped collection.  The capped collection is a collection as a pre-defined size that acts as a sort of ring-buffer.  Once then collection is full it starts overwriting the documents.  For iterating over the collection you simply create a "tailable" cursor you will need some way of identifying the "last document processed (even a simple "done" flag in the document could work but it would have to exist when the document is inserted). If you truly can't modify the documents in any way then you could even save off the last processed document somewhere and use a course time stamp to (approximate the start position) and look for the last document before processing more documents.

The only real issue with this solution is that you will be limited in the number of documents you can write in the collection and it won't grow over time.  There are limits on the write operations you can perform on the documents (they can't grow) but it does not sound like you are modifying the documents.

The second option, which is more complex, is to use the oplog.  For a standalone configuration you will need to still pass the -replSet option to create and use the oplog.  You will just not configure the oplog.  In a sharded configuration you will need to track each "replica set" separately.  The oplog contains a document for each insert, update, delete done to all collections/documents on the server.  Each entry contains a timestamp, operation and id (at a minimum).  Here are examples of each.

Insert

```js
{ "ts" : { "t" : 1362958492000, "i" : 1 }, 
  "h" : NumberLong("5915409566571821368"), "v" : 2, 
  "op" : "i", 
  "ns" : "test.test", 
  "o" : { "_id" : "513d189c8544eb2b5e000001" } }
```

Delete

```js
{ ... "op" : "d", ..., "b" : true, 
   "o" : { "_id" : "513d189c8544eb2b5e000001" } }
```

Update

```js
{ ... "op" : "u", ..., 
  "o2" : { "_id" : "513d189c8544eb2b5e000001" }, 
  "o" : { "$set" : { "i" : 1 } } }
```

The timestamps are generated on the server and are guaranteed to be monotonically increasing. which allows you to quickly find the documents of interest.

This option is the most robust but requires some work on your part.

I wrote some demo code to create a "watcher" on a collection that is almost what you want.  You can find that code on [GitHub](https://github.com/allanbank/mongodb-tricks). Specifically look at the code in the [com.allanbank.mongodb.demo.coordination](https://github.com/allanbank/mongodb-tricks) package.

HTH, Rob

Answer (score 1):

You **can** actually use timestamps if your _id is of type ObjectId:

```
prefix = Math.floor((new Date( 2013 , 03 , 11 )).getTime()/1000).toString(16)
db.foo.find( { _id : { $gt : new ObjectId( prefix + "0000000000000000" ) } } )
```

This way, it doesn't matter where the source of the event was or when it was,
it only matters when document insertion was recorded (higher than previous timer)

Of course, it is schema-less and you can always set a field such as isNew to true, 
and set it to false in conjunction with your query / cursor

Comment: Can't modify event in db, just consume it.